# woocommerce coupon - get all listed products ids

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I working on a website that generate coupon when someone register i have code it -

```
$coupon_code =  "ex".$resulted_coupon_code ;// Code

$amount = '20'; // Amount
$discount_type = 'percent_product'; // Type: fixed_cart, percent,     fixed_product, percent_product

$coupon = array(
'post_title' => $coupon_code,
'post_content' => '',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_author' => 1,
'post_type'  => 'shop_coupon'
 );

$new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );

// Add meta
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'discount_type', $discount_type );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'coupon_amount', $amount );
update_po st_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'yes' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', '4454,4452,4451,4449' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'exclude_product_ids', '' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit', '1' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit_per_user', '1' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'expiry_date', '' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'apply_before_tax', 'yes' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'free_shipping', 'no' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'customer_email', $user_email );
```

**now how can i to get the coupon products ids ??**
like from this

update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', '4454,4452,4451,4449' );

i want to retrieve  these 4454,4452,4451,4449

Comment: i am working on to get these like this 

$fields = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $id);
 
 foreach( $fields as $field ) {
  return $field;
 }
will update here if it works

Comment: What is `$id`? It needs to be the `meta_key`, and you aren't going to be able to loop over the results unless it's an array (it's not).

Answer (score 3):

WooCommerce is storing these values in the `postmeta` table, so you can use the [`get_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to retrieve the product IDs.

```
get_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', true );
```

To get all of the coupon post types first, then loop over them to get the products, then loop over them to get the product post types, you would use the following:

```
// get all coupons that are published 
$coupons = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'shop_coupon',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
) );

// loop through the coupons
foreach ( $coupons as $coupon ){
    // get the product ids meta value
    $product_ids = get_post_meta( $coupon->ID, 'product_ids', true );
    // make sure something has been saved
    if ( !empty( $product_ids ){
        // convert from comma separated string to array
        $id_list = explode( ',', $product_ids );
        // loop over each ID
        foreach( $id_list as $product_id ){
            // get the product for each ID
            $product = get_post( $product_id );
            // each product associated 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', get_post_meta( 4461, 'product_ids', true ));
```

try to use that code

Comment: yes working Thanks for full code it was life save :)

Comment: How is this valid? Where did the `4461` ID come from? Update does not return the IDs, it only sets them.

Comment: actually its other master coupon that is already built in woocommerce

Comment: I'm guessing you work with @RamanSingh? This is not a valid answer for SO, it includes information that is specific to your application and would not be helpful to others.

Comment: yes right

actually  its other master coupon that is already created in woo-commerce. I wanted to just clone it -   like when someone register, A auto coupon generate for that user but i did not want to edit the all coupons when products change in coupon so I have create a master coupon from where it get all products ids and other info and clone for new user. You have given us right idea many thanks for it!